# iOS: Call actionsheet from tabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uiactionsheet

I've looked at all other answers for this topic on Stackoverflow but don't get really further. I've set up my Tabbar controller in Storyboard. I've defined the icons for the tabbar items also in Storyboard, the titles however I've set via code in their respective view controllers since my app offers multi-language support.

Now I want one single tabbar button which doesn't segue to another view but just calls an actionsheet. No matter on which other tabbar I am. So my questions are:

1. Where do I add this tab bar button? Because all other buttons I can only define after creating the segue to the new view controller
2. Where do I place the code for the action sheet?!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very clued up on the tabbar, however i would do the following:
Assuming you are using a TabBarController View or a Central View With a TabBar in it.

In the -viewDidLoad

```
NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];

UIViewController *sheet= [[UIViewContoller alloc] init];
sheet.title = @"Sheet";
sheet.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage....];

[tmp addObject:sheet];

[self.tabBarController setviewControllers:tmp];

self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
```

Then place the following

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if([viewController.Title isEqualToString:@"Sheet"])
    {
        //ActionSheet create code here
        retrun NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```